# Assigning value to variable from a select count

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I've been programming a lot in sql recently but I'm still a newby and don't know a lot of the rules for the language and when the compiler doesn't help much I really don't know what to do.

In this case I got three errors:

```
Error(5,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following: (...)
Error(5,125): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:     * (...)
Error(22,20): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member constructor map
```

Here's the code, a trigger that inserts into a MENSALIDADE table if the date difference on CONTRATO.DATA_CONTRATO and today's DATE (more specifficaly the month difference) is lesser than 8 and if they have any registers in FATURA where ESTADO is 'Nao pago' (sorry for portuguese but it's 'Not paid'):

```
create or replace TRIGGER ANULAR_CONTRATO BEFORE DELETE ON CONTRATO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
valor NUMBER;
juro NUMBER;
BEGIN
juro := (SELECT COUNT(N_FATURA) FROM FATURA WHERE (EXTRACT(month FROM FATURA.DATA_FATURA) = (EXTRACT(month FROM SYSDATE))));
valor := (50 + juro);
IF DELETING THEN
IF ((MONTHS_BETWEEN(:OLD.DATA_CONTRATO, SYSDATE)) <= 8) THEN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT (FATURA.CODIGO_CLIENTE) FROM FATURA, CONTRATO WHERE (FATURA.CODIGO_CLIENTE = CONTRATO.CODIGO_CLIENTE)) THEN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT (FATURA.CODIGO_CLIENTE) FROM FATURA, CONTRATO WHERE ((FATURA.CODIGO_CLIENTE = CONTRATO.CODIGO_CLIENTE) AND (FATURA_ESTADO = 'Nao Pago'))) THEN
      INSERT INTO MENSALIDADE (N_MENSALIDADE, CODIGO_CLIENTE, N_CONTRATO, VALOR, DATA_FIM) VALUES (SEQ_MENSALIDADE.NEXTVAL, CONTRATO.CODIGO_CLIENTE, CONTRATO.N_CONTRATO, valor ,CONTRATO.DATA_FIM_CONTRATO);
    END IF;
  END IF;
ELSE
  IF EXISTS (SELECT (FATURA.CODIGO_CLIENTE) FROM FATURA, CONTRATO WHERE (FATURA.CODIGO_CLIENTE = CONTRATO.CODIGO_CLIENTE)) THEN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT (FATURA.ESTADO) FROM FATURA, CONTRATO WHERE (FATURA.CODIGO_CLIENTE = CONTRATO.CODIGO_CLIENTE) AND (FATURA_ESTADO = 'Nao Pago')) THEN
      INSERT INTO MENSALIDADE (N_MENSALIDADE, CODIGO_CLIENTE, N_CONTRATO, VALOR, DATA_FIM) VALUES (SEQ_MENSALIDADE.NEXTVAL, CONTRATO.CODIGO_CLIENTE, CONTRATO.N_CONTRATO, valor ,CONTRATO.DATA_FIM_CONTRATO);
    END IF;
  END IF;
END IF;
END IF;
END ANULAR_CONTRATO;
```

The first to errors probably I can't do what I'm doing the I'm doing but some help on how to do it properly would be really appreciated.
The third one I have no idea why is happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SELECT INTO` in `PL/SQL` to set values returning from `SELECT` queries. Can you change it as follows and see what error you get after that?

Also `IF EXISTS` is not valid in Oracle, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717136/using-if-exists-select-in-a-before-insert-trigger-oracle).

I guess, you cannot get the values of the deleted row with `CONTRATO.DATA_FIM_CONTRATO`, instead, you need to write `:old.DATA_FIM_CONTRATO`. This time, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355171/create-trigger-to-insert-into-another-table).

```
create or replace TRIGGER ANULAR_CONTRATO BEFORE DELETE ON CONTRATO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
valor NUMBER;
juro NUMBER;
cond1 NUMBER;
cond2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(N_FATURA) INTO juro FROM FATURA WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM FATURA.DATA_FATURA) = EXTRACT(month FROM SYSDATE);
valor := 50 + juro;
IF DELETING THEN
    IF (MONTHS_BETWEEN(:OLD.DATA_CONTRATO, SYSDATE)) <= 8 THEN
        SELECT COUNT(FATURA.CODIGO_CLIENTE) INTO cond1 FROM FATURA, CONTRATO WHERE (FATURA.CODIGO_CLIENTE = CONTRATO.CODIGO_CLIENTE) AND (FATURA_ESTADO = 'Nao Pago');
        IF cond1 > 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO MENSALIDADE (N_MENSALIDADE, CODIGO_CLIENTE, N_CONTRATO, VALOR, DATA_FIM) VALUES (SEQ_MENSALIDADE.NEXTVAL, :old.CODIGO_CLIENTE, :old.N_CONTRATO, valor ,:old.DATA_FIM_CONTRATO);
        END IF;
    ELSE
        SELECT COUNT(FATURA.ESTADO) INTO cond2 FROM FATURA, CONTRATO WHERE (FATURA.CODIGO_CLIENTE = CONTRATO.CODIGO_CLIENTE) AND (FATURA_ESTADO = 'Nao Pago');
        IF cond2 > 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO MENSALIDADE (N_MENSALIDADE, CODIGO_CLIENTE, N_CONTRATO, VALOR, DATA_FIM) VALUES (SEQ_MENSALIDADE.NEXTVAL, :old.CODIGO_CLIENTE, :old.N_CONTRATO, valor ,:old.DATA_FIM_CONTRATO);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;
END ANULAR_CONTRATO;
```

Comment: Error(8,10): PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only

This happened for line 8 and 14

Comment: I've updated my answer by replacing IF EXISTS clauses by comparing the counts and eliminating the unnecessary IF clauses.

Comment: It corrected a lot of stuff, but it has this one now

Error(18,193): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here (it was translated but directly goes to this)  on line 18 and 13.

It complains about CONTRATO.DATA_FIM_CONTRATO inserting into DATA_FIM, they are both DATE (type) does it have anything to do with that?

Comment: Learning with you. :) I've tried to correct the parts where you get the deleted row's values.

Comment: ahhh of course, I remembered that in the if's and not there... typical error :p
Thank you (I know comments thanking are to be avoided but this one was long and you sticked with me, so yeah, breaking the rules!)

Comment: I also enjoyed/learned from it, thank you for sticking with me too. :)

Answer (score 2):

This will help:

```css
 SELECT COUNT(N_FATURA) into juro
 FROM FATURA 
 WHERE (EXTRACT(month FROM FATURA.DATA_FATURA) = (EXTRACT(month FROM SYSDATE)));
```